# Gimp exports blank png image!

Tags: gimp, png

I'm trying to use Gimp to export a small line-style icon with a transparent background. It looks good in Gimp (black icon on the checkerboard of transparency), but the image disappears when exported as .png or .gif - it comes out with a totally transparent image file! .jpg of the same image works, but I lose the transparency.

I've tried other images, and it works fine. This is the fairly standard black circle with an 'i' in the middle.

Comment: Hi DrWhat, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: It should work - could you save your image as a native GIMP file (.xcf) and upload it somewhere for us to figure out what goes?

Comment: Something related to antialiasing? A too thin stroke? I second @jsbueno proposal.

Comment: Hi, you guys are great, and sorry for the tardy reply - weekend and work are my only excuse. Back to the fun stuff: I've uploaded the files to: [this site](https://www.transferbigfiles.com/3e38a75e-4822-4363-95c3-ddf1e9512ac6/1CMaE5h1QB3Kmgux1MFY9Q2) - visible only for 5 days. There is the gimp file, the visible jpeg and the invisible .png. The line graphic does have very thin strokes.

Comment: Your layer size is smaller than the image size. Not sure if/why this has anything to do with it, but after I did a "zealous crop" then exported PNG was OK.

Comment: That is good enough for me. I wanted to know if I was doing something wrong, and if there's a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in GIMP (or maybe libpng) - the only layer in your image doesn't cover the whole canvas. But the PNG file format can actually handle such offsets, so it should still show up in the exported file in this case.

Please file a bug for this in GNOME Bugzilla and attach the files you had uploaded previously:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GIMP&component=Plugins&version=2.8.14&op_sys=All

Comment: Hello and welcome. GD.SE is not a discusdion board if you have a question post a question. Do not post discussions as answers.

Comment: Hi Sam! As joojaa says, we follow a strict Q&A format (as opposed to a forum format), so I converted your answer into a comment because it doesn't answer the question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!